# JavaScript redirect from Tumblr to WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, tumblr

I've read a lot of topics about redirecting Tumblr to WordPress, but I still can’t find a  suitable solution.

Here is the problem: I want to redirect [jeby.tumblr.com](http://jeby.tumblr.it), a **Tumblr** blog, to the new [jeby.it](http://jeby.it), a **WordPress** (WIP) blog with a custom domain and web space etc. I’ve already imported all contents, now all I want is to “automagically” redirect every single post from

```
jeby.tumblr.com/post/[POST ID]/some-slug
```

to

```
jeby.it/2012/05/some-slug
```

I know that the post year and month are available in the Tumblr HTML code, as they are used to compose the permalink. I can’t use `.htaccess` redirects because the Tumblr blog is hosted by Tumblr.

I’ve done the same thing with Blogspot, where I found a plugin that created the right JavaScript code to paste into the Blogspot model and get automatic redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have realized already, you will need to do the redirection client side. How to achieve that is a matter of Tumblr’s [theme templating system’s possibilities and limitations](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes).

- **The year and month of a post** are [available as `{Year}` and `{MonthNumberWithZero}`](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#dates) tokens respectively; that gets you `2012` and `05`.
- **The post slug**, however, is not available as a token (not sure if this is an intentional omission – post slugs are optional on Tumblr; you can manually set one, but if you don’t your post just goes by its numeric ID) – so you will have to parse it out of the link inserted by [the `{Permalink}` token](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts).
- **Redirection can only take place on single-post pages.** Unluckily, there is no template based way to make sure you target only these, as the beauty and limitation of Tumblr’s theme DSL is that it is defined as one page: you get a `{block:Posts}` block and Tumblr does the figuring out how many posts to display inside that. That means that `meta http-equiv="Refresh"` tags are out of the question, as they would also be included in all non-single-posts pages.

Luckily, Tumblr does let you include arbitrary JavaScript in your template, and that is the way to go:

1. add the following line inside the `{block:Posts}` block:

   ```
   <span class="redirdata">{Year},{MonthNumberWithZero},{Permalink}</span>
   ```

   Style your `redirdata` spans with `display:none` in your CSS to hide them (or style them inline – considering their intended use, there is little point in being dogmatic).
2. now add a script to your `<head>` to parse these and redirect to the WordPress URL. As you want to do this for every possible visitor, i.e. as cross-browser compatibly as possible, I recommend using [*jQuery*](http://jquery.com/). Include it with:

   ```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

   or any other hosted source (see [the jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) for CDN URLs). Then add the following script:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){ 
           if ( $('.redirdata').length === 1) {
               var redirdataTokens = $('.redirdata').text().split(',');
               if (redirdataTokens.length === 3) { 
                   var redirectTo = 'http://jeby.it/'+redirdataTokens[0]+'/'+redirdataTokens[1]+'/'+redirdataTokens[2].replace(/.*\//, '');
                   window.location = redirectTo;
               }
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```

   and your single-post page should automatically redirect all visitors to the WordPress post page (if they have JavaScript enabled, of course). I am sure you will figure out to adapt this to tag archives, searches and such, if need be.

*Caveat Empteor:* this will only work if the slugs of your WP posts match the slugs of your Tumblr posts – crucially also in the case of Tumblr posts with no textual slug (meaning you WP slug needs to match the numeric Tumblr post ID in that case).

Comment: thank you, is exactly what I need but I've not understood where to put the $function... etc

Comment: @user1389100: just put in a *script* tag inside your template’s *head* after the jQuery script tag, i.e. `<script type="text/javascript">…</script>`

Comment: mmh... not working. Maybe I've to revert back to a "standard" tumblr theme before doing this?

Comment: @user1389100: my bad, mix up of jQuery elements and JS arrays – corrected, try the revised code above.